# Next.js multiple .env files

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dotenv

I am new to Next.js and in my project, I installed dotenv(https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and created a .env file in the project root and everything works fine.

Ex. API_BASE_PATH=http://localhost:8000/api

Then, I created another .env file named it as .env.testing in there, I have different values for API_BASE_PATH.

so, how can i switch between those .env in local development?

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3001",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "npm run build && next export"
  },
```

I want to add it to scripts.

Comment: Have a look at the `env-cmd` library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a script like the following

```
"scripts": {
  "env1": "DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=./.env next dev",
  "env2": "DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=./.env.testing next dev"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I'll share another way that I use:

One `.env` file

```
ENV=development // change to the env you want
DEV_VAR='dev-example'
STAGE_VAR='stage-example'
PROD_VAR='prod-example'
```

then in my
`next.config.js`

```
module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  let exampleVar;

  switch(process.env.ENV) {
    case "development":
    exampleVar = process.env.DEV_VAR;
    break;
    
    case "staging":
    exampleVar = process.env.STAGE_VAR;
    break;

    case "production":
    exampleVar = process.env.PROD_VAR;
    break;

    default: 
    exampleVar = process.env.DEV_VAR;
    break;
  }

  return {
    ...defaultConfig,
    env: {
      exampleVar,
    },
    // ...other next config options
  }
}
```

Then, in your code, you can use:

```
process.env.exampleVar
```

Then, when you develop, you just switch the `ENV` value to the environment you want to work in.

NextJS lets you use a function for your config:
[next.config.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction)